# Wifi Adapter not found - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wireless, 22.04

My sister's computer can't access the internet. It just says "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found". After that it asks me to make sure the Wi-Fi adapter is plugged in/turned on. She was using Ubuntu 20.04, but installed Ubuntu 22.04 in the hopes of fixing it. It didn't fix it. I also tried running sudo lshw -class network command in the terminal. At first it says "usb", but then that disappears and is replaced with a new line. No output. When I run `lsusb`, it gives me the following output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b723 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP TrueVision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:b00b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Realtek Bluetooth 4.2 Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

When I run: `lspci --nnk | grep Net`, there is no output.

Comment: As is, there is not enough info to help. Does it have a "wifi adapter"? If yes, which one (make/model)? Add the outputs of `lsusb` and `lspci -nnk | grep Net`. ...no screenshots please, just copy/paste the text itself.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Then post output of `lspci`